# lotusscript and dir function

Tags: function, lotusscript, lotus, dir

I have one problem, and it drives me crazy,
Here is a line of code

```
qdName$ = Dir(fDir, ATTR_DIRECTORY)
```

fDir is a directory path. 
Aim: I want to retrieve only Directory list under fDir path 
Reality: I get all objects, directories, files, etc, what I doing wrong?

Here is a piece of code

```
qdName$ = Dir(fDir, 16)
While qdName$ <> "" 
If qdName <> "." And qdName <> ".." And InStr(1, qdName$, ".JPG", NoCaseNoPitch) = "0" Then
            folders = folders + 1
            If InStr(1, qdName, "tmp") = 0 Then
                Name fDir + qdName As fDir + "tmp" + SetDoc.counter(0)
                qdName$ = "tmp" + SetDoc.counter(0)
                Set item = SetDoc.replaceItemValue("counter", CStr(CInt(SetDoc.counter(0)) + 1))
                Call SetDoc.save(True, True)                
            End If
            dList(dNo%) = qdName$
            dNo% = dNo% + 1
            qdName$ = Dir$()
        Else 
            qdName$ = Dir$()
        End If
    Wend
```

Comment: Works for me here. please show more code and tell us about the version of notes and os you use. I GUESSS you have no `Option declare` and did not use `%include "lsconst.lss"`, so that ATTR_DIRECTORY = 0 instead of 16

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424919/lotusscript-search-windows-directory-for-subdirectories-and-files-recursion

Comment: I don't have Option Declare directive, and it's not the case I guess, about Include directive it does`t help, where can I find lss files, are they system files? About my client, it's 8.5.3, and server is 6.5.4 under windows 2003

Answer (score 1):

Although the code is not complete, I think it is clear from comments what happens: 
There is no `Option declare` in the options- section of the code.

That means: The variables do not have to be declared. Any used variable will automatically be an empty variant.

ATTR_DIRECTORY is a constant in lsconst.lss (found in program- directory of Notes- Client) and has the value 16 as can be read in the designer help:

> 0 Normal file ATTR_NORMAL
>    2  Hidden file ATTR_HIDDEN
>    4  System file ATTR_SYSTEM
>    8  Volume label    ATTR_VOLUME
>    16 Directory   ATTR_DIRECTORY

In case of not including lsconst using the statement `%include "lsconst.lss"`, ATTR_DIRECTORY will be empty. As this is an optional parameter for dir, it will be handled as if it was not there - default handling is ATTR_NORMAL.

As a solution you should ALWAYS add `Option Declare` to your code and declare any used variable as this is a best practice to avoid such strange errors.
To get the constants defined by notes in addition use the %include statement.

Another possibility would be to use the number value instead of the constant:

```
qdName$ = Dir(fDir, 16)
```

should give the right result.

Comment: But dude, I forgot to comment, even if I write 16 (numneric value) instead I mentioned above problem remains :(

Comment: Included lsconst.lss, set declared option and corrected undeclared variables, problem remains same